Testcontainers container.getHost() is behaving differently Locally vs. GitLab pipeline
tl:dr;
Testcontainers container.getHost() behaves differently in maven lifecycle step and GitLab CI-Pipeline.

on the local machine container.getHost() is replaced with localhost
In the Gitlab pipeline container.getHost() is replaced with the actual HostIP

Context:
Used:

Maven
Tested host systems

local

Apple M2 Pro (2023)

IntelliJ Ultimate (& OpenJDK)


Linux (Kubuntu: 23.10)

IntelliJ Community Edition (& Coretto)




external

GitLab CI-Pipeline





Versions:

Java 21 (OpenJDK & Amazon Coretto)
Junit-Jupiter: 5.9.3
Testcontainers: 1.19.3
SpringBoot: 3.2.4

RestClient & Rest Template



Why RestClient & Rest Template?
Although RestClient it considered state of the art compared to RestTemplate (spring.io: April 2024) ...
... the two are giving different error feedback (as follows).
Setup
Assume 3 java Microservices in a Junit-Testcontainers setup like:
Container1   <-   Container2   <-  Validator
Container2 needs Container1 and a Validator lifts both in an Junit-Testcontainers environment, watching its communication.
Validator is not a live system, just an integrationtest-system.
Accordingly:

Container1 is started
Container1's port is written into Container2's env.
Container2 is started.
During startup Container2 tries to contact Container1's actuator endpoint.

    // Create a common network for all containers
    @ClassRule
    public static Network network = Network.newNetwork();

    @ClassRule
    public static GenericContainer<?> C1 =
            new GenericContainer<>(C1DockerImage)
                    .withExposedPorts(C1Port)
                    .withNetwork(network)
                    .withNetworkAliases("C1")

    @ClassRule
    public static GenericContainer<?> C2 =
            new GenericContainer<>(C2DockerImage)
                    .withExposedPorts(C2Port)
                    .withNetwork(network)
                    .withNetworkAliases("C2")

    static {
        // Start C1
        C1.start();
        C1BaseURL = "http://" + C1.getHost() + ":" + C1.getMappedPort(C1Port);

        // Start C2
        C2.withEnv("C1_URL", C1BaseURL);
        C2.start();

        logger.info("C1-Url given to C2 via ENV-Variable:   " + C1BaseURL);
    }

Accordingly:

All containers are attached to the same network
C1BaseURL looks like http://localhost:51059
Here 51059 is the host-system's port, which is mapping to C1's exposed port.

So far -> so good   :)
Behaviour
Three (3) environments are distinguished:
C2's Junit Test
Here a Testcontainers environment is started with C1 inside.
Be aware, C2 is running in IntelliJ Maven Test livecycle
Hence, C2 is not in an explicit Docker-Container.
C1's exposed port is wrapped by testcontainers and the proxy-port it given to C2.
C2 connects and everything is fine.
It works like a charm - just as expected.
Validator's junit test
Next, the Validator runs its IntelliJ Maven Test livecycle.
Hence, C2 is now inside an explicit Docker-Container.
The URL given to C2 remains a pointer to http://localhost:TestcontainersProxyPortToC1.
Assumption:

C2 does not find C1, as C2 is searching for C1 in its own container.

The assumption is fulfilled:

RestTemplate:   Connection refused
RestClient: null

GitLab CI-Pipeline
Within the GitLab CI-pipeline using the same Repository, the same Java-code, reproducable ...

Validator's junit test

http://HostIP:TestcontainersProxyPortToC1
is sufficient for C2 to connect to C1



The same code succeeds in the GitLab CI-Pipeline because localhost is replaced with the actual machines HostIP.
Confusion
My assumption is that both ..

Validator's junit test (local on mac)
Validator's junit test (GitLab pipeline)

.. have to behave in the same manner.
Both C2-containers shall succeed or fail connecting via one of ..

http://localhost:TestcontainersProxyPortToC1
http://HostIP:TestcontainersProxyPortToC1

Any other suggestionshow to fix this?
Is there annother Testcontainers-command, which always resolves the HostIP-Address?
Any help is appreciated   :)

Problem is still existent ...

Is there annother Testcontainers-command, which always resolves the HostIP-Address?

AFAIK there is no such 'Testcontainers-command' ...
Divergent behaviour on C1.getHost() remains (April 2024).

local: C1.getHost() => "localhost"
Gitlab: C1.getHost() => "HostIP"

There is no clue, how C1.getHost() determines when which answer has to be delivered.
... Workaround
The localhost's IP is LOCALLY always the Testcontainers HostIP.
But in the GitLab Ci-Pipeline the IP differs from the HostIP.
Hence C1's IP is for GitLab always a DIFFERENT HostIP in contrast to the runner.
Consequently the following changes in previously given code have to be made:
        C1BaseURL =
                "http://" + getHostIp(C1) + ":" + C1.getMappedPort(C1Port);

The custom function looks likt this:
    private static String getHostIp(GenericContainer<?> C1) {

        if (C1.getHost().equals("localhost")) {
            try {
                return InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return C1.getHost();
    }

Still no success?
You may need to dig deeper: Getting the IP address of the current machine using Java
